# mapstruct can not map property list of model to list of String

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jdbc

how can I map difference model list string to list model my code below;

my TaskList.class

```
@Getter
@Setter
private List<TaskGroupList> groupIds;
```

my TaskResponse.class

```
@Getter
@Setter
private List<String> groupIds;
```

My TaskGroupList class

```
@Getter
@Setter
private String ownerId;
```

My TaskListMapper.class

```
 public abstract List<TaskResponse> toAllTaskListResponse(List<TaskList> taskList);
```

Comment: posted new answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mapping to a List, I think you need to use IterableMapping annotation. Refer below link -

https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#implicit-type-conversions

It has an example for list to list conversion

```
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {
  @IterableMapping(numberFormat = "$#.00")
  List<String> prices(List<Integer> prices);
}
```

So, in your scenario, you could use the annotation. Also, as there is a List of List Objects, nested iterations are needed as below -

```
@IterableMapping(qualifiedBy = IterableMapping.class)
List<TaskResponse> toAllTaskListResponse(List<TaskList> taskList);

@IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "taskGroup")
List<String> map(List<TaskGroupList> task);

@Named("taskGroup")
default String map(TaskGroupList t) {
    return t.getOwnerId();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer when I use that annotation I have an error says that; 'nullValueMappingStrategy', 'dategormat, 'qualifiedBy'' and 'elementtargetType' are undefined in @IterableMapping define at lest one of them'

Comment: I updated by post. One of the strategy is needed as mentioned in the error

Comment: Thank you so much I think it will work on top of that I have @AfterMapping annotation gie me an error. What is the best approach for this ?

Comment: Can you post your related code ?  What is the error which you are getting ?

Comment: also if this answer your question, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer

Answer (score 0):

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CarListMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "groupIds",target = "groupIds",qualifiedByName = "toGroupId")
    TaskResponse toTaskResponse(TaskList taskList);

    List<TaskResponse> fromAllTaskList(List<TaskList> carDtoList);

    @Named("toGroupId")
    static List<String> toGroupId(List<TaskGroupList> groupIds){
        return groupIds.stream()
                .map(taskGroupList -> taskGroupList.getOwnerId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

It worked for me

Comment: Thank you so much for yor answer. I will use this approach soon :)